# jquery selector after only '.class:first' and before only '.class:last'

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to find and style the class before only the `:last` selector (real second-last),
and the class after only the `:first` selector (real second).

I've tried with `nth-child()` and `nth-last-child()`,
but they dont select only the very second-last and only the very second classes over the entire page..

```
$('.myClass:first             ').addClass("myClassStart");
$('.myClass:nth-child(2)      ').addClass("myClassStart2");
$('.myClass:nth-last-child(2) ').addClass("myClassEnd2");
$('.myClass:last              ').addClass("myClassEnd");
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/66TsU/2/)**

**NOTE:** only the `:first`, and the `:last` selectors actually work well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to achieve this is to use the [:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector:

```
$(".myClass:eq(1)").addClass("myClassStart2");
$(".myClass:eq(-2)").addClass("myClassEnd2");
```

`:eq()` is zero-based, passing it `1` matches the second element in the set. When fed a negative number, `:eq()` matches backwards from the end of the set, starting at `-1`, so `-2` matches the next-to-last element.

You will find an updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/66TsU/3/).

Comment: It works perfetcly! I've already tested the :eq() but probably in the wrong way.. Thank you bro! :)

Comment: The documentation for `:eq()` (the selector) incorrectly states that it is also zero-indexed when using a negative number. The documentation for `.eq()` (the method) is correct however.